# Problem with \makebox and the unit in the dimensions

Tags: boxes, lengths, units

I want to superpose a text to some other object (in this aces a picture). My idea is to store the picture in `\mabox`, to display it with in a  `\makebox` with 0 width and height, then to display the text thru a second `\makebox`, with width and height equal to those of `\mabox`. My attempt fails, because `\wd\mabox` delivers a length with unit, and `\makebox` expects a length without unit. How could i do it better?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox\mabox
\sbox{\mabox}{\includegraphics[scale=0.10]{Pingouin}}
\makebox(0,0)[b]{\put(0,0){\usebox\mabox}}
\fbox{\makebox(\wd\mabox,\ht\mabox)[b]{\put(0,0){\parbox{\wd\mabox}{\blindtext}}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it be a solution to use TikZ?  In that case, take a look at [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)

Comment: You can use `\raisebox` and `\rlap` to remove `height` and `width` as well. Also, `adjustbox` allows for that (see key `bgimage` for example).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't tell anyone I told you, but you can go

```
\def\unitlength{}
\sbox{\mabox}{\includegraphics[scale=0.10]{Pingouin}}
\makebox(0pt,0pt)[b]{\put(0pt,0pt){\usebox\mabox}}
\fbox{\makebox(\wd\mabox,\ht\mabox)[b]{\put(0pt,0pt){\parbox{\wd\mabox}{blindtext}}}}
```

Note that having made `\unitlength` unitless, you have to put explicit units in places that normally take an integer.

The alternative is to use `\strip@pt` defined in LaTeX eg this use where LaTeX is switching between unit and non-unit font size representation

```
   \edef\f@size{\strip@pt\@tempdimb}%
```

but often it's easier just to use units everywhere in picture mode, then you are not restricted to using the same units throughout.

Comment: ok, i will not tell anyone ;) But the command `\strip@pt` makes exactly what i want : just put a `\strip@pt` before `\wd\mabox` and `\ht\mabox` in my second makebox. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`picture`](http://ctan.org/pkg/picture) package, so that

```
\makebox(1cm,3in){...}
```

is accepted; you're allowed to put explicit and implicit (that is, expressed as register values) dimensions in all commands of the `picture` environment.