# Require height of certain box

Tags: vertical-alignment, vertical

I want a way to create a command (or the equivalent) like

```
\boxspecifiedheight{8in}{This is some text.}
```

which uses 8 inches of vertical space. If the sentence was replaced by 5 or 6 sentences, that part of the code would also use 8 inches of text. The goal is to align text on the front and back of a 2-sided page without having to compute what to plug into vspace on my own.

Mark

Comment: Please have a look at [Problem with \makebox and the unit in the dimensions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48230/121799).

Comment: see `\parbox[pos][height][contentpos]{width}{text}`, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Zarko. I used minipage which has a height option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\def\commonwidth{1.3in}

\def\front{
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t][\commonwidth]{\textwidth}
\noindent
This is something.
This is something.
This is something.
This is something.
This is something.
This is something.
This is something.
This is something.
\end{minipage}
}
\def\back{
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t][\commonwidth]{\textwidth}
\noindent
This is something too.
\end{minipage}
}

%\def\mydata{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
\def\mydata{1,2,3,4,5}


\begin{document}


\foreach \x in \mydata { \front }

\newpage

\foreach \x in \mydata { \back }

\newpage

\end{document}
```