# How to add multiple differently colored borders around a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, border

I want to draw a node to be filled with a table containing data, and it should have (three) differently colored adjacent borders around it. Couldn't find anything in the PGF manual, on the Net, nor on this forum, so I came up with this MWE...

Nesting three tikzpicture environments feels like a BIG amateuristic kludge to me, and if not, how do I get rid of the white space in between the borders?

```
\documentclass[pdftex,dutch]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{lichtgrijs}{RGB}{232,232,232}
\definecolor{DE.rood}{RGB}{222,0,0}
\definecolor{DE.geel}{RGB}{255,207,0}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle,line width=0.5mm,draw=black] at (0,0)
{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[rectangle,line width=0.5mm,draw=DE.rood] at (0,0)
 {\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle,line width=0.5mm,draw=DE.geel,fill=lichtgrijs] at (0,0) {Vliegtuig};
  \end{tikzpicture}};
 \end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: My kludge]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[dutch]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\definecolor{lichtgrijs}{RGB}{232,232,232}
\definecolor{DE.rood}{RGB}{222,0,0} % Rood in Duitse vlag
\definecolor{DE.geel}{RGB}{255,207,0} % Geel in Duitse vlag

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style = {draw=#1, line width=0.5mm,inner sep=0.25mm}
                        ]
\node (n1) [box=DE.geel,
            fill=lichtgrijs, inner sep=2mm] at (0,0) {Vliegtuig};
\node (n2) [box=DE.rood, fit=(n1)] {};
\node (n3) [box=black,   fit=(n2)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Some Notes:

- never nest `tikzpicture` in `tikzpicture`, which may raise unexpected side effects;
- the `fit` library of `tikz` is used to get what you want;
- you can define node style, which merges all nodes in one, but I'd like first to know whether the illustrated result is what you're looking for :-)

**addendum:** 
here is a three-color node variation. In particular, `append after command=` option in a node style is used for the middle and the outer colors:

```
\documentclass[dutch]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\definecolor{lichtgrijs}{RGB}{232,232,232}
\definecolor{DE.rood}{RGB}{222,0,0} % Rood in Duitse vlag
\definecolor{DE.geel}{RGB}{255,207,0} % Geel in Duitse vlag

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
tcb/.style = {% three color border
              draw=DE.geel, fill=lichtgrijs,
              line width=0.5mm,inner sep=2mm,
              append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
                    \node [draw=DE.rood, line width=0.5mm,
                           inner sep=0.25mm,fit=(\LN)] {};
                    \node [draw, line width=0.5mm,
                           inner sep=0.75mm,fit=(\LN)] {};
              }}}
                        ]
\node (n1) [tcb] {Vliegtuig};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as before.

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{standalone}% to avoid cropping
\usepackage{babel}% not needed for MWE
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{lichtgrijs}{RGB}{232,232,232}
\definecolor{DE.rood}{RGB}{222,0,0}
\definecolor{DE.geel}{RGB}{255,207,0}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[line width=0.5mm]
  \node[draw=black,inner sep = 1.5mm] (n1) at (0,0) {Vliegtuig};
  \draw[DE.rood] ($(n1.south west)+(0.75mm,0.75mm)$) rectangle ($(n1.north east)+(-0.75mm,-0.75mm)$);
  \draw[DE.geel] ($(n1.south west)+(1.25mm,1.25mm)$) rectangle ($(n1.north east)+(-1.25mm,-1.25mm)$);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Did you use another text font? P.S. Good job!

Comment: That's a nice answer! (+1) If you made it a `pic` with a tiny bit of extra effort you could make the thing rotatable, which the other answers could not (unless one wants to add `rotate fit` over and over).

Answer (score 7):

Without TikZ, only `\colorbox`es.

I've added `\usepackage{picture}` to use the widths/lengths not  specified in multiples of `\unitlength`.

I've added `\usepackage{calc}` for convenience, to do calculations in `\setlength` (you can avoid it if you use `\addtolength`).

I've used `\makebox(\myxxxwidth, \myxxxheight){...}` to specify the width and total height of the boxes.

I've calculated the width of the boxes this way:

```
width of the border + width of the content + width of the border
```

that is

```
width of the content + double of the width of the border
```

You can set the border widths as you like.

The same for heights.

I've created a new command `\mybox` for convenience, you can even modify it to set the border widths as a parameter/parameters, if you like.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,dutch]{article}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{picture}% see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48238/101651
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\mygraywidth}
\newlength{\mygrayheight}
\newlength{\myyellowwidth}
\newlength{\myyellowheight}
\newlength{\myredwidth}
\newlength{\myredheight}
\newlength{\myblackwidth}
\newlength{\myblackheight}

\definecolor{lichtgrijs}{RGB}{232,232,232}
\definecolor{DE.rood}{RGB}{222,0,0}
\definecolor{DE.geel}{RGB}{255,207,0}

\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{%
    \setlength{\mygraywidth}{\widthof{#1}+4mm}
    \setlength{\mygrayheight}{\totalheightof{#1}+4mm}
    \setlength{\myyellowwidth}{\mygraywidth+1mm}
    \setlength{\myyellowheight}{\mygrayheight+1mm}
    \setlength{\myredwidth}{\myyellowwidth+1mm}
    \setlength{\myredheight}{\myyellowheight+1mm}
    \setlength{\myblackwidth}{\myredwidth+1mm}
    \setlength{\myblackheight}{\myredheight+1mm}
    \colorbox{black}{\makebox(\myblackwidth,\myblackheight){%
        \colorbox{DE.rood}{\makebox(\myredwidth,\myredheight){%
            \colorbox{DE.geel}{\makebox(\myyellowwidth,\myyellowheight){% 
                \colorbox{lichtgrijs}{\makebox(\mygraywidth, \mygrayheight){%
                #1}}%
            }}%
        }}%
    }}%
    }

\begin{document}

\mybox{Vliegtuig}

\vspace{4ex}

\mybox{Do you like it?}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would've been the best solution... but unfortunately there appears to be no option to set the border width.

Comment: @Petoetje59 See my renewed answer. Let me know if you like it.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is to use `preaction` to draw the node multiple times. Here I define the `rainbow` style that can be user as `rainbow={color1,color2,...}` where `color1` is the most external color.

The advantage of this method is that it can be used with any shape and with arbitrary number of colors.

**Note:** the node should be filled to hide the inner overlapping.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
% the german colors
\definecolor{lichtgrijs}{RGB}{232,232,232}
\definecolor{DE.rood}{RGB}{222,0,0}
\definecolor{DE.geel}{RGB}{255,207,0}
% define the rainbow style
\tikzset{
  next color/.style={preaction={draw=#1,next width}},
  next width/.code={
    \pgfkeysalso{line width/.expanded={\rainbowwidth pt}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rainbowwidth}{\rainbowwidth-\rainbowstep} % decrease the rainbow width
    \xdef\rainbowwidth{\rainbowwidth} % set the rainbow width global
  },
  rainbow/.style={next color/.list={#1}},
  rainbow/.prefix code={
    \edef\rainbowstep{\the\pgflinewidth}
    \foreach[count=\i]~in{#1}{} % count the number of colors
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rainbowwidth}{\i*\rainbowstep}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\tikz
  \path
    node[line width=0.5mm,fill=lichtgrijs,rainbow={black,DE.rood,DE.geel}] at (0,0) {Vliegtuig}
    node[cloud,line width=1mm,inner sep=-4,fill=white,rainbow={red,orange,yellow,green,blue,purple}] at (3,0) {Regenbogen};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice work!

Comment: For me this is the best solution here. Also because it can be rotated and so on without extra efforts.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a library for that, and you can make things much more automatic by just supplying the list of colors. Then it boils down to saying

```
\node[inner sep=8pt,line width=2pt,multicolor rectangle={DE.rood,DE.geel}] {Vliegtuig};
```

This strategy can be applied to other node shapes, too, if needed.

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,dutch]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{lichtgrijs}{RGB}{232,232,232}
\definecolor{DE.rood}{RGB}{222,0,0}
\definecolor{DE.geel}{RGB}{255,207,0}

\begin{tikzpicture}[multicolor rectangle/.style={draw,path picture={
\foreach \CPP [count=\YPP] in {#1}
{\draw[\CPP] ([xshift=\YPP*\pgflinewidth,yshift=\YPP*\pgflinewidth]path picture bounding box.south west)
rectangle ([xshift=-\YPP*\pgflinewidth,yshift=-\YPP*\pgflinewidth]path picture bounding box.north east); }}}]
\node[inner sep=8pt,line width=2pt,multicolor rectangle={DE.rood,DE.geel}] {Vliegtuig};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case it bugs you that you have to set the `inner sep` by hand, this can be taken care of at the expense of a slightly longer code.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that "I want to draw a node to be filled with a table containing data" means "I want to type a table containing data with a colorfull background and border". For this I prefer to use `tcolorbox`. First option uses `tcbox` which adjusts the box to its contents while the second solution adjusts table size to text width unless you set some other `width`. `borderline` options allows to define extra color borders.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, tabularx, colortbl}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\definecolor{lichtgrijs}{RGB}{232,232,232}
\definecolor{DE.rood}{RGB}{222,0,0}
\definecolor{DE.geel}{RGB}{255,207,0}

\newtcbox{mytable}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    sharp corners,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
    fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
    colback=lichtgrijs,
    colframe=DE.geel,
    colbacktitle=white,
    coltitle=black,center title,
    borderline={.5mm}{-.5mm}{DE.rood},
    borderline={.5mm}{-1mm}{black},
    #1 }

\newtcolorbox{tctable}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    sharp corners,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
    fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
    colback=lichtgrijs,
    colframe=DE.geel,
    colbacktitle=lichtgrijs,
    coltitle=black,
    center title,
    borderline={.5mm}{-.5mm}{DE.rood},
    borderline={.5mm}{-1mm}{black},
    tabularx={XYYYYY},
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\mytable{
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries My table}\\
\midrule
Red & 1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 10000.00\\
Green & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 & 14000.00\\
Blue & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 & 6000.00 & 18000.00\\
Sum & 6000.00 & 9000.00 & 12000.00 & 15000.00 & 42000.00\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\begin{tctable}[title=My table]
Red & 1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 10000.00\\
Green & 2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 & 14000.00\\
Blue & 3000.00 & 4000.00 & 5000.00 & 6000.00 & 18000.00\\
Sum & 6000.00 & 9000.00 & 12000.00 & 15000.00 & 42000.00
\end{tctable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's an embarrassment of choices here! As usual I'll go for the shortest and simplest that does the job, and that was Zarko's code.