# How to draw clusters with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to recreate the cluster diagrams shown below for my homeowrk. Help?

[image: Cluster expansion for the dilute gas.]

[image: More cluster diagrams.]

Comment: See [documentation - What is the minimum one needs to know to use TikZ? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9116/what-is-the-minimum-one-needs-to-know-to-use-tikz) first -- but there may be some better package I don't know

Comment: For the space between node and line perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477589/how-to-add-multiple-differently-colored-borders-around-a- (or `outer sep`/`inner sep` although the documentation is a little unclear on that)

Comment: Actually for the space between node and line use `shorten`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19987/drawing-a-bijective-map-with-tikz for an example (and of course the documentation)

Comment: Off topic: I may be missing something, but I don't see a matching close bracket at the end of the line beginning with the = sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finished the job only as exercise after many attemps. Surely it is not a "clean" and "easy" code and it is not the same to 100%. But I have tried to give you an answer.
**An advice**: the next question put a minimal working example! :-).
**PS: It is not made with tikz: sorry.**

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{parskip}


\begin{document}
\[\underset{1}{\bullet}\qquad \xymatrix@R=.2pt@C=.2pt{
\underset{2}{\bullet} \ar@{-}[rr] & & \underset{3}{\bullet}}\qquad \xymatrix@R=.2pt@C=.2pt{
\underset{4}{\bullet} \ar@{-}[rr] & &\underset{5}{\bullet} \ar@{-}[rr]& & \underset{6}{\bullet}}\quad \cdots \underset{N}{\bullet}\]
\[b_2=\resizebox{25pt}{!}{\stackon[-2pt]{}{\xymatrix@R=.2pt@C=.2pt{
{ \bullet} \ar@{-}[rr] & & {\bullet}}}}=
\int d^3\vec{q}_1\cdots\text{you could to continue to complete it.}\]
There are four diagrams contibuiting to $b_3$, leading to
\[b_3=\resizebox{25pt}{!}{\stackon[-4pt]{}{\xymatrix@R=.2pt@C=.2pt{
& {\bullet} \ar@{-}[ldd] & \\
&  & \\
{\bullet} \ar@{-}[rr]&  &{\bullet} }}} \quad +\quad \resizebox{25pt}{!}{\stackon[-4pt]{}{
\xymatrix@R=.2pt@C=.2pt{
& {\bullet} \ar@{-}[rdd] & \\
&  & \\
{\bullet} \ar@{-}[rr]&  &{\bullet} }}}\quad +\quad \resizebox{25pt}{!}{\stackon[-4pt]{}{
\xymatrix@R=.2pt@C=.2pt{
& {\bullet} \ar@{-}[ldd]\ar@{-}[rdd] & \\
&  & \\
{\bullet} &  &{\bullet} }}}\quad +\quad \resizebox{25pt}{!}{\stackon[-4pt]{}{
\xymatrix@R=.2pt@C=.2pt{
& {\bullet} \ar@{-}[ldd]\ar@{-}[rdd] & \\
&  & \\
{\bullet} \ar@{-}[rr]&  &{\bullet} }}}
\]
\[=\int d^3\vec{q}_1\cdots\text{you could to continue to complete it.}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not with tikz but did the job. Thank you very much.

Comment: @egreg please can you see of my code Is good?